# Failed to get resource ID for resource type 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' and resource name. Error: ExpiredServicePrincipal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

When the release is being triggered on AzureDevops, it fails on 'App Service Deployment' stage with this `Error: ExpiredServicePrincipal`

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error may be caused by your service principal secret was expired, the service principal is used in your service connection in DevOps org.

Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the Azure portal, make sure you select the correct AAD tenant which the service principal belongs to, in the `App registrations` -> search for the client id of the service principal(you can find it in the service connection) -> find the AD App related to the service principal -> `Certificates & secrets` -> `New client secret`, then copy it and update the `Service Principal Key` in your service connection -> verify connection.

[image]